# Is there anyway to identify per user quota hits for Gmail API from google developer console?

Tags: python, gmail, gmail-api, google-developers-console

I'm using Gmail APIs to process email messages in a user's mailbox. I make sure I don't flood the Gmail APIs by routing them through a single pipeline but I quite often get a Too Many Requests error from users. 
Should I implement a quota monitor system (per user) of my own or is there a dashboard where I can check the quota limit per user?

Answer (score 1):

There is a dashboard to check your quota limit per user. This can be found in **IAM & Admin** -> **Quotas** in the Developer Console.

[image]

Just filter the API you want to check under **Service**. You can now monitor your per user limit.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I can get the quota limits from the Dashboard. I wanted to know if there is a way to identify that the quota is getting hit or the rate at which the queries are done for a user? I know it is not available in the dashboard. The only way is to start recording it from the application?